# Exchange/Outlook rule to parse message subject and redirect/forward to embedded address within subject?

Tags: email, exchange

I have situation where a client wants to pass emails we send on to their employees, but their Exchange system is locked down such that most employees are unable to receive messages from outside their organization.  They are apparently unable to have a whitelist with our sender address (I'm not familiar with Exchange admin so I don't know why *that* isn't an option). They also do not have a publicly available SMTP server that we could use to authenticate and send from their own system, or at least say they don't.

So the next option we're entertaining is sending our messages all to a single address on their system, with an email address embedded in the subject.  Then they would like some sort of rule  that would parse the subject for the embedded address and then redirect/forward the original message to that address.

Is there any way to do something like this from the Exchange side? Custom macro filter rules or something? Alternatively, if not that is there a way to do it from the Outlook side?

I don't know the version of Exchange yet, but will edit once I find out.  But at this point I'm just trying to figure out what it is that I'm looking for in the first place or what options might be available to implement such a thing.

edit:
I've been told this is Exchange 2003.  I also did come across something about 'Transport Rules' which sounds like it might be what I'm looking for?

Comment: if this is a client with which you have a good working relationship, then they should be able to put you in touch with whoever manages their Exchange org or least one of their local sysadmins to come up with the best solution rather than trying to hack together an e-mail parser that lets messages through despite their e-mail config

Answer (score 2):

Noticed this recently so apologies for the tardy response. If you have no access to the exchange system and they have no way logging work with their email provider transport rules will be of no use to you as they are server side. Here is some info on them:

[Transport Rules](http://www.ehow.com/list_7626330_exchange-2003-transport-rules.html)

But TBH if you have access enough to enable transport rules you can get your domain white listed.

Here is a quick rundown of the initial setup to help with any request you may have to put to their supplier / sysadmins

http://www.servolutions.com/support/config_exchange_2003.htm#section2

as mentioned try and avoid creating an email parser as that is nightmare work and once again you'll probably need access to the exchange system anyway.

Hope it went well or if it's still an issue good luck.

Comment: Thanks!  They ended up implementing a workaround where a workstation is dedicated sitting running Outlook with a custom VBScript rule parses out incoming messages and forwards them on.  Incredibly hackey, I know!